# How can I optimize LLVM assembly cross-compiled with gcc?

Tags: gcc, assembly, optimization, llvm, alpha-cpu-architecture

I am using LLVM to generate Alpha assembly. Their Alpha ISA support is experimental and I  cannot find a way to work around a bug. If I use -O0 during LLVM bytecode-to-Alpha assembly creation, the assembly generated is fine.

I want optimized assembly, however. Is there some option in gcc (which is my final cross compiler) that would optimize the assembly? I tried -O3 while converting the Alpha assembly to object file, but I did not see any optimization happening. Is it even possible to do back-end optimization after assembly creation?

Comment: It is of course possible to optimize assembly language. It's just another language after all, so all standard optimization techniques apply. Google "optimizing assembler" for some real-life examples. But gcc doesn't do it.

Comment: Yeah while in theory it's possible, I doubt many compiler writers would find it worthwhile to spend much time trying to do so. Gcc is even better than most others in that regard since they at least optimize functions containing inline assembly - but then everyone looked at GCC inline assembly code knows that this comes at quite some cost in complexity..

Comment: Don’t work around the bug then. Fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **optimized assembly**, you obviously should ask LLVM for it. So pass -O3 to llc, not to gcc.